# Extract part of JSON in ansible playbook

Tags: json, ansible, ansible-facts

I want to extract a part from a json extra vars input and use this as a variable in further commands.

The extra vars being parsed towards ansible is:

```
{
 "problemUrl": "https://xxxxx.xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx.xxxx/e/58b59a93-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-91bb5ca1f41c/#problems/problemdetails;pid=-5484403941961857966_1631165040000V2",
}
```

I want to extract the part -5484403941961857966_1631165040000V2 and store it into a variable.

```
- name: get pid from URL
  set_fact:
    pidproblem: "{{ problemUrl | urlsplit('fragment') | regex_search('pid=(.+)', '\\1') }}"
            
- name: show pid
  debug:
    var: pidproblem[0]
    
- name: update problem with output
  when: state == "OPEN"
  uri:
      url: https://xxxxx.xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx.xxxx/e/58b59a93-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-91bb5ca1f41c/api/v2/problems/"{{ pidproblem[0] }}"/comments
      method: POST
      headers:
        Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
        Authorization: Api-Token xxxxx
      body_format: json
      body: "{\"message\":\"TEST\",\"context\":\"TEST\"}"
```

Could the issue reside in the fact that the id is subsituded as "6551567569324750926_1631192580000V2" instead of 6551567569324750926_1631192580000V2?

```
"url": "https://xxxxx.xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx.xxxx/e/58b59a93-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-91bb5ca1f41c/api/v2/problems/\"6551567569324750926_1631192580000V2\"/comments"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `urlsplit` [filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) which can split a URL into known segments. We can use this to break down the URL and get the last `fragment`, i.e.

```
"{{ problemUrl | urlsplit('fragment') }}"
```

Gives...

```
problems/problemdetails;pid=-5484403941961857966_1631165040000V2
```

Now this gives us a more "manageable" string. We can do a `regex_search` (with groups) on this, to get the `pid`, like:

```yaml
    - name: get pid from URL
      set_fact:
        pid: "{{ problemUrl | urlsplit('fragment') | regex_search('pid=(-.+)', '\\1') }}"

    - name: show pid
      debug:
        var: pid[0]

    - name: update problem with output
      uri:
        url: "https://xxxxx.xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx.xxxx/e/58b59a93-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-91bb5ca1f41c/api/v2/problems/{{ pid[0] }}/comments"
        # other params
```

Comment: This already helps me on the good way! I only face 1 problem that once I use the variable in the next task it results in a bad substitution. I will adjust my main post with the result.

Comment: The quotes should be around the entire URL itself, not just the variable substitution. Like: `url: "https://.../api/v2/problems/{{ pidproblem[0] }}/comments"` (edit: answer updated)

Answer (score 0):

Not super-reliable as we don't know how your url can change, but you could use some regex filter to extract the pid value:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    problemUrl: '{ "problemUrl": "https://xxxxx.xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx.xxxx/e/58b59a93-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-91bb5ca1f41c/#problems/problemdetails;pid=-5484403941961857966_1631165040000V2;other=false" }'
  tasks:
  - name: set_fact some paramater
    set_fact:
      pid: "{{ (problemUrl | from_json).problemUrl | regex_replace('.*pid=(?P<pid>[^;]*).*', '\\g<pid>') }}"
  - name: "update"
    debug:
      msg: "{{ pid }}"
```

Comment: Hi @guido. Thank you for your suggestion. To answer your question, the problemUrl will always be in the same format.

"https://xxxxx.xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx.xxxx/e/58b59a93-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-91bb5ca1f41c/#problems/problemdetails;pid=-5484403941961857966_1631165040000V2"

The only value that can change is the "pid" value. When running your suggestion i receive an error. I will update this in the mail post.

Comment: If you copy and paste my snippet above and run locally, it works, you need to adapt to your local play.

Comment: if i just use your suggestion. It still give:

    ```{"msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value ({'pid': \"{{ (problemUrl | from_json).problemUrl | regex_replace('.*pid=(?P<pid>[^;]*).*', '\\\\g<pid>') }}\"}), and could not be converted to an dict.The error was: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)\n\n```